# Switching power source using P-channel MOSFET

Tags: power, mosfet

In a below schematic, PVBUS and VBUSIN are both attached to USB VBUS of two different USB ports (so +5V). The goal is to be able to power +3V3 regardless of whether VBUSIN is present or not. If VBUSIN is +5V PVBUS is unconn, the IC (SPX3819) is powered by VBUSIN, the other way around (VBUSIN - unconn, PVBUS - +5V) by PVBUS, when both are +5V then powered by PVBUS.

**Does this schematic implement this logic? Do I need to add a resistor (100k?) between PVBUS and VBUSIN?**

If this does not work, then how could this logic be implemented without incurring voltage loss? (any IC that provides this logic already?)

OR is the 2 separate VBUS connected in parallel not a concern at all and there is no need for such switching?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work.

If PVBUS is disconnected, there is nothing to pull the gate down, so the PMOS may not conduct.  Even if there was, once it conducts, voltage from VBUSIN will pull the gate back high and stop conduction.

Think about it this way, if you always want VIN to be high, then the gate of that MOSFET will always be high...they are directly connected together!

Another potential issue:  If PVBUS is high and VBUSIN is low, current can backfeed through the body diode on your PMOS.  This may or may not be a problem, depending on how that side of the circuit works.

You could try and remedy these situations with resistors and/or diodes, but you will be dropping voltage along the way.

A common approach here is to use a power management IC.  You might look at something like an [LTC4412](http://www.linear.com/docs/1527).

If you don't care where the current comes from and you can tolerate a 0.6 V drop, just put a diode on each leg to prevent back feeding.

Comment: Thanks! How can I fix this to implement this logic while not incurring large voltage loss? It does not necessarily need to be mosfet, though this is the first component that comes to my mind when thinking of this problem. "current can backfeed through the body diode on your PMOS", that is a (minor) problem indeed, so schottky there should fix it I guess.

Comment: I've added those questions to the main post,  would appreciate some insight on this.

Comment: See my edits, where I recommend a power management chip.

Comment: Thanks! That IC is pretty pricy compared to the rest of bom. Technically if having to +5V in parallel is not a concern (from electrical perspective), then I think last suggestion is a better one. Will a couple of schottky diodes do the job just as well there?

Comment: Yes, they have a nice low voltage drop and switch quickly.  The only issue is they leak *slightly* in reverse bias, but I doubt that will be a problem for you.

Answer (score 2):

The answer given already, addresses the question very well. Obviously, the simplest approach is to have two diodes (Schottky) for each supply.

Another thing you could try and it's still going to be cheap, is something like the following (in line with what you're initially doing and probably within budget since I saw that was one of your concerns):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmopgnm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If V1 is present and V2 is not, then the PMOS is will be on (initially through the body diode, but very shortly after the MOSFET will turn on—once VGS(on) is established ~-5V) and this is the path for current flow. If V2 is present and V1 is not, then the PMOS is off (VGS ~ 0V) and the current flow will be from V2, through the Schottky, and out to the regulator. If both V1 and V2 are present, the path through the Schottky is still the one that will have the current flow, so V2 will rule.

The *advantage* of this configuration is that (if you care about very much the voltage drop) there is at least one path, that provides lower drop: The path V1 takes (\$I^2R_{DS(ON)}\$). This is useful if you had a weaker source in V1 and would like to maximize it (e.g batteries). If for example, RDS(on)=100m\$\Omega\$ at VGS=-5V and the current going into the regulator is 1A, the drop in the V1 path is about 0.1V versus 0.3V or 0.4V in the V2 path. This [PMOS](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/FDC642P_F085-D.PDF), as an example, presents a 65m\$\Omega\$ (max) on-resistance at -4.5V

V2's path is still not too bad, but the path through the RDS(on) of the PMOS presents an easier path (lower impedance). So you would place your more robust source at V2 and the weaker at V1.

Hope this helps.